# Ways to persist SignalR connection

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

I am creating web application, which let's users to communicate with so called chat.

In order to enable such communication, I use SignalR library. I create connection at first visit to my page (main page). So JS code, which creates connection, creates variable used to configure connection.

Then user enters chat room, which is different page, so new JSs are loaded etc. The one, which held connection variable is now unavailable. But now I need that connection to send messages in my chat room.

So this variable must be "transfered" over to next scripts.

So, **what would be the way to actually persist connection through whole session on the website**?

Comment: Connections are going to be unique from each connection point, you can't transfer them to a new page. Look into Groups in SignalR. Put your user, based on their userID, not the connection, into a group called "Lobby" when they log in. If they enter a chat room, even if on another page, put them into a group named "Chat Room xxx". Messages can be delivered to the group regardless of what page they are on as long as you have a valid client method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I got my answer.

It was suggested that I should use ASP NET Identity, which is very valid, but I already created simple authentication and users management. It isn't safe and as half good as ASP NET Identity (I looked throught it and got my head around it), but it's just personal project, not production one, so if it evolves I might switch to Identity or even implement one myself ;) But it's not the case.

It required little bit of extra steps, so:

1. I needed to enable sessions in ASP.NET Core, I used [this article](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-use-session-in-asp-net-core/) for this purpose. Having that, I can persist my user login and provide it to user ID provider for signalR
2. Adding cutsom user ID provider for SignalR in .NET:

I needed to create such class

```
public class UserIdProvider : IUserIdProvider
{
  public static readonly string SESSION_LOGIN_KEY = "loggedUser";
  private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
  
  public UserIdProvider(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor) 
  {
    _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
  }

  public string GetUserId(HubConnectionContext connection)
  {
    var session = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session;
    session.TryGetValue(SESSION_LOGIN_KEY, out byte[] loginBA);
    if (loginBA == null)
    {
      return null;
    }

    return new string(loginBA.Select(b => (char)b).ToArray());
  }
}
```

So, after logging I can set login in `Session`, so it becomes "state" variable, and use it in above class.

Also, one need to add it in ASP services, like below (in `Startup.ConfigureServices`):

```
services.AddSingleton<IUserIdProvider, UserIdProvider>();
```

There also one thing, which still need to be set: in `UserIdProvider` we need to access `Session` through `HttpContext`. In order to use `HttpContext`we need to specify it like below (also in `Startup.ConfigureServices`):

```
services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
```

which passes `HttpContextAccessor` to serices constructors.

After all this, you can access users in SignalR `Hub` with their logins, which is set in `Context.UserIdnentifier`

This also enables sending messages to specific user, just by passing their login (frontend client just chooses user), like below:

```
public async Task SendMessage(string message, string user)
{
  await Clients.User(user).SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", message).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

**NOTE** There was one problem though. Browsers on computer didn't persist sessions, which I solved by (also in `Startup.ConfigureServices`):

```
services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
{
  // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
  options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => false; // <~~~~ This needs to be set to false
  options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
});
```

Without it, you need to be carefull with cookies, if you don't accept them on a site, it won't work, as user's login won't be persisted.

Answer (score 1):

On the server side, you can send the message to specific user via [user id](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/mapping-users-to-connections#iuserid-provider):

```
var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(Context.User);

await Clients.User(user.Id).SendCoreAsync("msg", new object[] { user.Id, user.Email });
```

On the client side, whenever the connection is started and the hub `msg` is listened, the user will receive the message:

```
connection.on('msg', function (...data) {
    console.log('data:', data);
});
```

By sending message(s) via user id, you don't need to care where the target user is.

---

```
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    private IUserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

    public ChatHub(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
    }

    public async Task GetInfo()
    {
        var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(Context.User);

        await Clients.User(user.Id).SendCoreAsync("msg", new object[] { user.Id, user.Email });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, interesting. But where did you get `_userManager` instance? What type is it?

Comment: @MichałTurczyn Sorry for late. I've updated my answer. You can use `_userManager` as a service through the hub constructor. Don't forget to enable `UserManager` service by calling [service.AddIdentity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.identityservicecollectionextensions.addidentity?view=aspnetcore-3.1) in the `Startup` class

Comment: I figured it out, thanks. I created my own custom identity service :) Thanks again, but I used cutsom identities provider instead of ASP Identity (I already manage users on my own)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but fianlly I fought my way through it :)